# Disable CoverFlow Scrolling until Popup Appears

Tags: android, coverflow

I am  using cover flow in my project and while display of cover flow on button click i am showing popup.

(Coverflow in android is the style to display images in line which is scrolled on touch as we generally see in media player and can be selected ;It's based on the Android Gallery widget and is used in the same way, with a ViewAdapter. My main aim when coding this coverflow widget was to create an easily re-usable component using the standard Android 2D libraries
reference :-  http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html)

s
 - now when popup is displayed i don't want my coverflow to
   scroll/navigate on touch i.e i want to disable coverflow untill popup
   is displayed

- i have already tried all the code below but it is not help full to
  disable coverflow.

  ```
          coverFlow.clearFocus();
          Popup.setFocusable(true);
          coverFlow.setClickable(false);
          coverFlow.setFocusable(false);
          coverFlow.setEnabled(false);
          coverFlow.setSelected(false);
  ```

  can any one help me out in this matter ?

Comment: You need to explain what `CoverFlow` is. There will be people who see your question and have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @unkown  how u done where u write below methods ? in your activity or in Coverflow class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what source code of CoverFlow you are using. But you can custom it.

Extend the CoverFlow (which already extends Gallery, i think), override the onTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent methods with return false if you don't want the CoverFlow scroll, and add the method to set this attribute.

The code maybe looks like :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

public void setScrollEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
```

And then you can set the CoverFlow scroll or not by using `setScrollEnabled` method

Comment: but what if i m not extending Gallery Class i m just using base adapter class  with simple fullscreen gallery component in xml.

Comment: you do not need extends Gallery Class because the CoverFlow already did it. You only need extend CoverFlow

Comment: @tsengvn  i used your solution but i m getting error once i tried to call this method from my fragment class i m using fancycoverflow from fragment ..... and i have made my custom adapter that extends public class MapAdapter extends FancyCoverFlowAdapter {    .... but here is the error list http://pastie.org/10268685

Comment: try it in  cover flow class

Comment: Doing this disables the click event of any item .....do u have any way...by which we can handle click of items...